# Postfix as gateway

Tags: postfix

I followed this guide verbatim:
http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#firewall

However, it results in local mail to `root` going to `root@localhost.mydomain.com`.
If I change that line in `/etc/postfix/virtual` to: `root  myuser@mydomain.com`
then it gets to me, so problem solved?

The problem is that anyone from outside can also send to `root` and it gets to me.  I've been trying to figure out how to have locally posted mail to `root` go to `myuser@mydomain.com` while preventing outside connections from doing so.

Comment: And where do you want the mail to go instead?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Basically, it's the following that will allow locally posted mail to be accepted, while rejecting the same mail from outside...

In main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
    reject_unauth_destination
```

In /etc/postfix/recipient_access:

```
root@mydomain.com  REJECT
```

Activate it:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_access
service postfix reload
```